# Checking if every specific item in list is in hashmap?

Tags: java, python, arrays, hashmap, jython

I'm bukkit jython/python plugin coder, but I'm stuck here. I have an array.array (so ArrayList) which is pregenerated by server, and returns list of online players.

That's this:

```
online = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()
```

So what I want? (check #hashcomments)

I created this HashMap():

```
channelList = HashMap()

@hook.command("channel", usage="/channel [channelname]", desc="Use this command to join an channel!",
              aliases = ["c", "cjoin", "cj"])
def channel(sender, command, args):
    channel = args[0]
    channelList.put(sender, channel) #so if player does /channel balkan command it puts his name and channel (balkan in this case) in hashmap...
    sender.sendMessage("%sYou've successfully joined %s %s %s channel!"%(bukkit.ChatColor.DARK_AQUA, bukkit.ChatColor.AQUA, channel, bukkit.ChatColor.DARK_AQUA))
    return True

@hook.event("player.PlayerChatEvent", "NORMAL")
def onPlayerChatEvent(event):
    p = event.getPlayer()
    message = event.getMessage()
    messagesubstring = message[:1]
    event.setCancelled(1)
    playername = event.getPlayer().getDisplayName()
       if messagesubstring == "!":
          plist1 = #How do I get this list? It's list of players that are in HashMap with "balkan" as second hashmap argument...
          userChannel = "balkan"
          online = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()
          lenghtonline = len(online)
          b = lenghtonline - 1
          a = 0
          if a <= b:
             if channelList.get(p) == userChannel:
                plist1.sendMessage("blabla")
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashMap.entrySet()` to iterate entries of a `HashMap`:

Java:

```
for(Entry<String, String> e: channelList.entrySet()){
     if(userChannel.equals(e.getValue()){
          pist1.add(e.getKey());
     }
}
```

In Jython you might need to call like this:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = channelList.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    Entry<String, String> e = it.next();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand you. I don't think this will output an array list with all playernames that have joined balkan chat before? To sum up: I have an array list of online players, which I need for checking if those players are in hashmap, but I want to get list of online players from hashmap that are in balkan chat (aka previously being put in HashMap by command)

Comment: This small excerpt shows how to iterate values of a map filled with `channelList.put(sender, channel)`. I'm sorry if didn't understand your problem.